# Fine Uploader session Thumbnails slow to load

Tags: c#, session, thumbnails, nancy, fine-uploader

I'm creating a mockup file upload tool for a community site using Fine Uploader.

I've got the session set up to retrieve the initial files from the server along with a thumbnail url.

It all works great, however the rendering of the thumbnails is really slow.
I can't work out why. So I hard-coded to use a very small thumbnail for each of the four files. This made no difference.

The server side not the issue. The information is coming back very quickly.

Am I doing something wrong? Why is fineuploader so slow? Here's screen grab. It's taking four seconds to render the four thumbnails.

[image: fine uploader rendering thumbs]

I'm using latest chrome. It's a NancyFX project on a fairly powerful machine. Rending other pages with big images on them is snappy.

Client side code:

```
thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/Content/js/fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/Content/js/fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            session: {
                endpoint: "/getfiles/FlickaId/342"
            },
```

Server side code:

```
        // Fine uploader makes session request to get existing files
        Get["/getfiles/FlickaId/{FlickaId}"] = parameters =>
        {
            //get the image files from the server
            var i = FilesDatabase.GetFlickaImagesById(parameters.FlickaId);

            // list to hold the files
            var list = new List<UploadedFiles>();

            // build the response data object list
            foreach (var imageFile in i)
            {
                var f = new UploadedFiles();

                f.name = "test-thumb-small.jpg"; // imageFile.ImageFileName;
                f.size = 1;
                f.uuid = imageFile.FileGuid;
                f.thumbnailUrl = "/Content/images/flickabase/thumbnails/" + "test-thumb-small.jpg"; // imageFile.ImageFileName; 

                list.Add(f);
            }

            return Response.AsJson(list); // our model is serialised by Nancy as Json!

        };
```

Comment: Is there an issue with file size?  I am not sending back the real file size yet.Thought that was just for display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, and was implemented both to prevent the UI thread from being flooded with the image scaling logic and to prevent a memory leak issue specific to Chrome. This is explained in the thumbnails and previews section of the documentation, specifically in [the "performance considerations" area](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/thumbnails.html#performance-considerations):

> For browsers that support client-generated image previews (qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews === true), a configurable pause between template-generated previews is in effect. This is to prevent the complex process of generating previews from overwhelming the client machine's CPU for a lengthy amount of time. Without this limit in place, the browser's UI thread runs the risk of blocking, preventing any user interaction (scrolling, etc) until all previews have been generated.

You can adjust or remove this pause via [the `thumbnails` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#thumbnails), but I suggest you *not* do this unless you are sure users will not drop a large number of complex image files.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response Ray.  Interesting. Is there any way to change this parameter just for the "initial files" loading session?  It doesn't seem right to have this pause when essentially all that is happening is for a list of image files urls to come back from the server and be displayed in the web page. If I was to write a js loop that put a series of <img> tags on the page the result would have no lag.  The pause should only really happen when a user is dropping file on the control. Or is that not possible?

Comment: The images are being resized to ensure they are all uniformly displayed. So this is much more then just simply rendering image tags.

Comment: ok, thanks. In this instance it will only be myself and a few others uploading files so it's not a big deal. I will reduce the time a little and live with it.